# Possible missing value with parameters in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, stripe-payments

I'm new to Rails and I have no idea what's going on here. The app I am building is an online store. The current functionality works, but the change I am trying to implement isn't working. As a starting point, I will show the working version that I have now. Here is my carts/show.html.erb file:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h2>My Cart</h2>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Total Price in Galleons</th>
            <th>Total Price in Muggle Currency</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <%= render(@cart.line_items) %>
            <tr>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td><%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price * 7.35) %></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </thead>
</table>

<br>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= link_to 'Back', products_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary whiteText' %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= link_to "Checkout", new_charge_path, :class => 'btn btn-success whiteText' %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= link_to 'Empty Cart', @cart, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to empty your cart?'}, :class => 'btn btn-danger whiteText' %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9"></div>
</div>
```

However, I am wanting to change the workflow a bit so that it uses my Order scaffold to redirect the user to an address confirmation page (orders/new.html.erb) after clicking "Checkout" on the Cart show page. Once the address is confirmed, it should then route the customer to the payments page, which is what the new_charge_path in my current Checkout link redirects to already.

So to start with, I am replacing the Checkout link and turning it from this:

```
<%= link_to "Checkout", new_charge_path, :class => 'btn btn-success whiteText' %>
```

to this:

```
<%= link_to "Checkout", new_order_path, method: :get, :class => 'btn btn-success whiteText' %>
```

This redirect functions as expected, and takes me to orders/new.html.erb, which contains the following:

```
<h1>Order Information</h1>

<br>

<%= render 'form', order: @order %>

<%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>
```

The form it renders contains the following code:

```
<%= form_for(order) do |f| %>
  <% if order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% order.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :first_name %>
        <%= f.text_field :first_name, size: 20, :value => current_user.first_name, :class => "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :last_name %>
        <%= f.text_field :last_name, size: 20, :value => current_user.last_name, :class => "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :address %>
        <%= f.text_area :address, size: 40, :value => current_user.address, :class => "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :city %>
        <%= f.text_area :city, size: 20, :value => current_user.city, :class => "form-control" %>
      </div>  

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :state %>
        <%= f.text_area :state, size: 2, :value => current_user.state, :class => "form-control" %>
      </div>  

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email, size: 40, :value => current_user.email, :class => "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :pay_type %>
        <%= f.select :pay_type, Order.pay_types.keys, prompt: 'Select a payment method', :class => "form-control" %>
      </div>

    </div>  



      <div class="col-md-6">

        <%= form_tag(payments_path, class: "form-inline") do %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag(:purchase_amount_cents, @cart.total_price) %>
          <div class="form_group">
            <%= label_tag(:credit_card_number, "Credit Card Number", class: "sr-only") %>
            <%= text_field_tag(:credit_card_number, "", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Credit Card #") %>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="form_group">
            <%= label_tag(:expiration_month, "Month", class: "sr-only") %>
            <%= text_field_tag(:expiration_month, "", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Month") %>
            <br>
            <%= label_tag(:expiration_year, "Year", class: "sr-only") %>
            <%= text_field_tag(:expiration_year, "", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Year") %>
            <br>
            <%= label_tag(:cvc, "Year", class: "sr-only") %>
            <%= text_field_tag(:cvc, "", class: "form-control", placeholder: "CVC #") %>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="form_group">
            <%= submit_tag("Purchase Cart", class: "btn btn-default", id: "purchase") %>
          </div>
        <% end %>

      </div>



  </div>


  <hr>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Proceed to Payment' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The payment options are credit card (Stripe) or Paypal. I will eventually add the Paypal functionality but Stripe API is all I have for now.

Here is my Order Controller:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :ensure_cart_isnt_empty, only: :new
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to new_charge_path}
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url, notice: 'Order was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :address, :city, :state, :email, :pay_type)
    end

    def ensure_cart_isnt_empty
      if @cart.line_items.empty?
        redirect_to products_path, notice: 'Your cart is empty!'
      end
    end

end
```

Here is my Charge Controller:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
    include CurrentCart
    before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]

    def new
    end

    def create #METHOD IS CALLED AFTER PAYMENT IS MADE
     # Amount in cents
     @amount = @cart.total_price

     customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
       :email => params[:stripeEmail],
       :source  => params[:stripeToken]
     )

     charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
       :customer    => customer.id,
       :amount      => @amount,
       :description => 'Customer',
       :currency    => 'usd'
     )

     Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id]) 

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to new_charge_path
    end 

end
```

Here's the problem. While the redirects work as expected, the @amount in the Charge controller is set to $0.00 if the order controller is used. If, however, the Cart links directly to the Charge controller, then the correct dollar amount is used. So, I am assuming that somehow the cart object is being lost or having its value reset.

Here is my set_cart method:

```
def set_cart
      @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
end
```

And here is my CurrentCart module:

```
module CurrentCart
  private
    def set_cart 
      @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      @cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    end
end
```

Comment: Does Stripe call back to `ChargesController#create` (in a webhook) once the charge is made?

Comment: I don't believe so.

Comment: Show the `set_cart` method and what do you have in `CurrentCart`

Comment: OK, I updated my question to include the set_cart method and the CurrentCart module.

Answer (score 0):

My idea you need to passing forward the value @cart.total_price from cart show form to order controller here some steps to do

inside your link (you pass the value as params)

```
<%= link_to "Checkout", new_order_path(total_price: @cart.total_price), method: :get, :class => 'btn btn-success whiteText' %>
```

inside order_controller (you get the params and put in instance variabel)

```
  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @temp_total_price = params[:total_price]
  end
```

inside order_form insert between your form_for tag, we need to put this in the form as hidden value, so it can be passing to create method for charge

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'total_price', @temp_total_price  %>
```

inside your class ChargesController create method you can get the total_price

```
@total_price = params[:total_price]
```

I know it's little bit log but probably this can help

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try that, I am getting an error in the Charge Controller indicating that the amount isn't being set.

Comment: try to tracing between view and controller, you can use puts command to trace for example inside order_controller after new command you can trace puts params[:total_price] check whether it's nil / 0 / other value

Comment: I tried displaying a notice in the Order create method using "at"cart.total_price. It displays the correct amount, so the Order Controller is definitely able to access the amount of "at"cart.total_price. For some reason though, the Charge controller cannot.

I'm using "at" in this comment because Stack Overflow won't allow the symbol.